# Microsoft cognitive services: Translator text: incorrect transliteration of Kanji to Latin? Is there a Bing site to test transliteration?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator, transliteration, kanji

I am trying to use Microsoft's Cognitive Services Translator Text to transliterate text. The results with Kanji do not appear to be correct.

Here are 3 examples of Kanji:

こんにちは
j-talk.com: Konnichiwa
Translate.Google.com transliteration: Kon'nichiwa
Bing translation: hello
Translator Text:
  Transliteration: connich  - *this result appears to be incomplete*
  Translation: Hello

烏丸通七条下ル 
Hand transliteration: Karasuma-Shichijō-sagaru
j-talk.com: Karasuma tsū shichijō sagaru
Translate.Google.com  transliteration: Karasuma dōri nana-jō kudaru
Bing translation: Karasuma-Dori Shichijo-Le
Translator Text API call: imartsunanajoukar
  *this result appears to be wrong. Japanese shouldn't have the letter "r"*

東塩小路町 721-1  Note: this is an address
Hand transliteration: Higashi-Shiokōji 721-1
j-talk.com: Higashi shiokōji machi 721-1
Translate.Google.com  transliteration: Higashishiokouji-chō 721 - 1
Bing translation: Higashi-Shikoji-machi 721-1
Translator Text: fails to transliterate because of the numeric characters.
  *the translation API handles the numbers, but the transliteration API doesn't.*

So I have 2 questions:
1) Will Microsoft correct/improve the Kanji transliteration? 
2) Is there a site like www.bing.com/translator where I can confirm that the transliteration results I get are to be expected?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for pointing out these issues. The Microsoft Translator engineering team is working to correct issues with Japanese transliteration and your examples were useful.

Microsoft Translator team